# insert new line after every character [batch-file]

Tags: batch-file, text

I am trying to create a batch-file script to convert a normal `.txt` document to one that is completely vertical. For example:

From:

```
This is a test document,
it is displaying characters on the same line.
```

To:

```
T
h
i
s

i
s

a

t
e
s
t

d
o
c
u
m
e
n
t
,

i
t

i
s

d
i
s
p
l
a
y
i
n
g

c
h
a
r
c
t
e
r
s

o
n

t
h
e

s
a
m
e

l
i
n
e
.
```

Comment: This site is not a free script writing service! Try it on your own first and when stuck, come back here, share your efforts and clearly describe what you have problems with! Read at least the [tour] and learn [ask] here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this will not completly fit your needs, but as a starting point you can try with

```dos
cmd /u /c"type normal.txt" | find /v "" > vertical.txt
```

This will start a `cmd` instance with unicode output. Inside this instance the `normal.txt` file is send to standard output. All the output from the `cmd` instance is piped into a `find` command that will see the null characters (the unicode output is a two bytes per character sequence, one of them a null or `0x00` ascii) as line terminators and will output a new line after each character. All the data is redirected to the output file.

Answer (score 1):

The following script is based on [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41692614) and avoids additional line-breaks in place of line-breaks that also occur in the original file:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "SPACE= "
set "FLAG=#"
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%C in ('
    cmd /U /C type "%~dpn0.txt" ^| find /N /V ""
') do (
    set "CHAR=%%C"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "CHAR=!CHAR:*]=!"
    if defined CHAR (
        echo(!CHAR!
        endlocal
        set "FLAG=#"
    ) else (
        if defined FLAG (
            echo(%SPACE%
            endlocal
            set "FLAG="
        ) else endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```